# Probability that three numbers obtained from a five sided spinner is the same?

Tags: probability

So I've been preparing for my upcoming GCSE exams, and in one of the past paper questions I was attempting, I faced this question:

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQco5.png)

I was able to do all the parts except the last one. According to what my teacher had instructed me about probability, The probability that Katrina gets the same number 3 times must be 1/125 (1/5)^3 however in the mark scheme the answer is 1/25. I consulted my teacher about this and he said that the mark scheme may have an issue itself! That baffled me and here I am guys, this is my first question so please go easy on me...

P.S I have consulted to every person that I know of, and no one has been able to give me a definitive answer, I have tried to search for a similar question but failed to do so, if you think this is a duplicate please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might think of this in the following way: There are no conditions on the first spin, so we have probability 1 of spinning something. To this we multiply the probability of getting the same spin the next time, which is clearly $1/5,$ and again the third time, giving $$1\times\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{25}.$$

Comment: ah I see, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The sample space is consists of all tuples $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ where $1\leq a_i\leq 5$. Hence there are $125$ possible outcomes which we assume equally likely. Then the event that she spins the same number $3$ times corresponds to the five sample points $(1,1,1); (2,2,2); (3,3,3); (4,4,4); (5,5,5)$ from which we obtain the probability
$$
\frac{5}{125}=\frac{1}{25}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have understood it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You correctly found that the probability of getting the same number is $\frac{1}{5^3}=\frac{1}{125}$. Since there are $5$ numbers on the spinner, the probabilities are added:
$$P(11111)+P(33333)+P(55555)+P(77777)+P(99999)=5\cdot \frac{1}{5^3}=\frac{1}{25}.$$